# Android : Toast appear when I fail to reach server when downloading

Tags: android, android-toast

I have a problem : when I download some files from my server on internet and he can't reach the server I have this message : "failed to connect to /myIP after 15000ms: isConnected failed: EHOSTUNREACH (No route to host)".

Why is android making a toast when I didn't ask for anything ?

PS : My downloading code is a basic one :

```
url = new URL(myUrl);
connection = url.openConnection();
connection.connect();

// download the file
input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream(), 8192);
// Output stream
output = new FileOutputStream(fileTemp);

data = new byte[1024];

while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
    // writing data to file
    output.write(data, 0, count);
}

// flushing output
output.flush();

// closing streams
output.close();
input.close();
```

And I'm 100% sure that the Toast isn't from my code (I deleted all my Toast just to be sure...)

Comment: Does this happen even after you've done "clean build"?

Comment: @Sufian Yes, no matter what I do I have this **** messages when i can reach host

Comment: Please add a bit more code so we can see how it all chains up.

Comment: @Sufian Damn I think I know why I have this problem... You could'nt solve it with what I gave you, my downloading code is in a for() loop so every time my code fail to connect it goes to catch() and then try reconnecting because of the for()... Sorry it was just that ^^'

Comment: It feels like one of those "I told ya" moments. :P When asking on StackOverflow, always put all of the relevant code, but before that try [Rubber duck debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) first. ;)

Answer (score 0):

This error will appear if the ip address you are using is not working. If you are working with server without static ip make sure you use the local ip and are connected on the same network as the server machine. Else you should make sure that the ip you are making the request to is working, you can test it using your browser to make sure its working before porting it to android.
Also sorround  your network code using a try{}catch block.

Comment: Yeah I know why he display the error, I just want to know if I can stop this message ? If he appear one time it's ok but he appear as long as the server is unreachable it's annoying...